# Minecraft JSON API Value to Percentage, then to Width

Tags: jquery, json, minecraft

I'm getting details for a Minecraft server from an API system (from http://mcping.net/) and then wanting to use the "online players" and "max players" to display a value, and also calculate a percentage, which will be used to fill the "width" of a bar.

For some reason, when using this on Enjin, I can only collect the "Online" amount of players, and the rest isn't collected. Have I done something wrong with the code, or is this an issue with Enjin (which the site is being hosted on)? How can I get around this if so?

**This code can be seen live on http://www.minevival.com/portal. Each bar will read the "online players", and the width of the progress bar should be the percentage of how full that server is.**

Here is the code:

```
function MainCheck() {
    $.getJSON("http://mcping.net/api/72.20.45.4:25577/online,max", function(json){
        var online = json.online;
        var max = json.max;
        var percentage = Math.round((online/max)*100).toFixed(0);
    if(online !== undefined) {
        $(".main-sr-only").html(online);
        $("#main-progress-bar").css("width", percentage + "%");
    } else {
        $(".main-sr-only").html("...");
    }
    setTimeout(MainCheck, 4000);
}); 
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because __this problem that can no longer be reproduced__ and __is unlikely to help future readers__. Also see: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3622940)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the curator of the API. I have fixed the issue and am working on pushing it to all of our servers. In the mean time, you may format your request ending with a forward slash as in the following example

```
https://mcping.net/api/72.20.45.4:25577/online,max/
```

Edit: The update is now pushed, the API should now ignore the query string

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the actual URL that's requested includes a timestamp query string parameter, which gets misinterpreted by the server as part of the 'max' field.

See [the ajax method documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), for which `.getJSON()` is a shorthand, which states:

> **cache** (default: `true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'`)
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. **Note:** Setting `cache` to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

---

I suggest that you switch to `.ajax()` and specify `cache: false`.